# Postfix Conditional MX Forwarding

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, email, postfix

So here's the problem.

"Someguy" wants to transfer his domain and website to me so I can take care of it. But Someguy's primary email address is "someguy@thatsite.com". If he transfers thatsite.com's DNS to me, the emails will no longer get to his provider.

I could just set the MX records for thatsite.com to point back to his email provider so he would keep getting his email, but then I couldn't have an email at thatsite.com.

What I need to do is configure Postfix so it sends only emails addressed to someguy@thatsite.com back to his provider's mail servers.

Comment: I don't get what you want. Are you hosting Email for thatsite or not? If not then you have no problem mailing to thatsite. If yes then this conflicts with his Email provider as you are the Email provider now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Manage domain mail on own postfix
2. Use [virtual_alias_maps](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html)

> virtual_alias_maps (default: $virtual_maps) Optional lookup tables
>   that alias specific mail addresses or domains to other local or remote
>   address. The table format and lookups are documented in virtual(5).
>   For an overview of Postfix address manipulations see the
>   ADDRESS_REWRITING_README document.
>
> This feature is available in Postfix 2.0 and later. The default value
>   is backwards compatible with Postfix version 1.1.
>
> If you use this feature with indexed files, run "postmap
>   /etc/postfix/virtual" after changing the file.